# Does 230v three phase have a high leg

Tags: power

I have an old printing press that needs to be looked up.  The nameplates on the equipment say 230 V three-phase . The building I am putting it in has 120 - 240 with a Delta high leg. I am worried that the high leg will  Will harm the equipment as it goes to a control panel with lots of relays.   My question is does all 230v three phase power have a high leg .

Comment: Post a picture of the plate on the equipment.

Comment: Those are just 2 of many phase and voltage configurations used by many countries. At least 14 by my count 10 years ago. You have a miss-match, as in not compatible. Supply us with details and maybe there is an adapter to be found. 120 - 240 with a Delta high leg is an old industrial/residential power feed that still exist today.

Comment: Do you have any idea where in the world does that old machine come from?

Answer (score 1):

A delta high-leg system has 240 volts line-to-line, but line to neutral is 120 volts line-to-neutral for two pf the three hot lines and 208 volts line-to-neutral on for the third (high) hot line. If a machine that requires three phases requires a neutral connection, you will have a problem with any component that is connected between line and neutral. A 240-volt wye system would normally have 139 volts from line to neutral for each of the three hot lines. However, I expect that a 240 volt wye system is even more rare than a 240-volt high-leg system. I would expect that everything inside a 240-volt, three-phase machine would be either a balanced three-phase load (motor) or a 240-volt, single-phase, line-to-line load.

Comment: Note: the common electrician's term for that high leg is "Stinger".  For good reason <grin>.